# How to automate data extraction and saving to text file in R - Pls i need very basic tutorials

Tags: r

I'm a newbie to working with R and barely learn how to write few lines of code.

I'm working with a large dataset that requires extracting each row of "data" + "header" to separate text files and saving with the name of the col1/row2 content... for example

```
Station Depth   4000 µm 2000 µm 1000 µm 500 µm  250 µm   125 µm 63 µm   4 µm    1 µm    0.4 µm
M1-2    0.9 0.42    0.56    0.63    2.67    32.30   41.92   18.62   0.00    2.88    0.00
M2-2    6.9 6.31    6.08    14.05   18.10   17.79   10.65   7.63    0.00    18.89   0.49
M3-2    3.3 0.26    1.74    4.71    11.78   66.53   5.38    2.01    0.00    7.27    0.32
M4-2    3.8 3.90    6.30    19.81   29.91   32.87   5.17    0.39    0.00    1.57    0.08
M5-2    4   0.00    1.42    5.40    18.94   42.06   22.57   5.47    1.18    2.37    0.59
```

for example I need to extract the header row and data row 1, and save to a text file using M1-2. Then, repeat same for data row2 (Header+data row2) and save as M2-2 and so on...

Bare in mind i'm just a newbie !!!

Comment: A `dput()` of source data-frames is always #spiffy. And, I'm assuming the *"text file using M1-1"* should have been "M1-2" instead of "M1-1"?

Comment: I think it's clear what you are trying to achieve. Write each data row with headers in a separate file. What have you tried so far? Please show your effort/ideas, it will help people directing you the right way.

Comment: As i said earlier- i'm new to the wonderful world of R. The only effort so far, was to spend 2 days extracting my data manually, i want to be able to save this time in the future...

Answer (score 2):

Similarly, in `base`:

```
lapply(rownames(dat),function(x) write.csv(dat[x,],file=paste0(x,'.txt')))
```

Answer (score 0):

If:

- your data frame is named `dat`
- the `Station` values are unique
- you want the files named `STATION-VALUE.dat`
- you don't want the row names

then:

```
library(plyr)
d_ply(dat, .(Station), .fun=function(x) {
  write.table(x, sprintf("%s.dat", x[1,]$Station), 
              row.names=FALSE, col.names=TRUE, sep="\t")
})
```

should work.

Comment: Can you guide me through the basics